# Problems with variable scope in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I'm fairly new to razor, kind of muddling my way through it to finish off some changes I made to the underlying c# code, and I'm running into a problem.

I need to use a settings property on an underlying object to get the correct configuration file to pull an image location from. I'm trying to change a hardcoded image into a configurable one.

What I have so far:

```
else
{
@{ 
     var prefix = Model.GetNameSpaceFromSettings();
     var configImgs = ChartColors.GetImgs(prefix);
}
<div style='float:left;'>
<img src='@Url.Content(Model.ComparisonChart(300, 250, false))' border='0' alt=''/>   
<p></p> 
<table width='295' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1' border='0' class='summarygridtablebackground' align="left">                       
<tr class='summarygridbackground'>
<td>
<div style="float:left; width:125px;"><img src='@configImgs.MyImg' border='0'></div>//This is where I'm working
</td>
</tr>
//a few more rows where I'm trying to eventually do the same thing
</table>
</div>
}
```

This doesn't work, with the message "The name 'configImgs' does not exist in the current context."

I read in another question that a common solution to scope problems was to put the variables into an @functions section, so I tried that, and it ended up looking like this:

```
else
{
@functions{ 
      string prefix = Model.GetNameSpaceFromSettings();
      Images configImgs = ChartColors.GetImgs(prefix);
}
```

This one fails with a message pair, "An object is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvx.WebViewPage.Model.get" (I tried referencing it with 'this' as well, and it said that 'this' was not available in the current context) and "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ASP.Myfile.prefix'"

I could really use some help here, thanks.

Comment: Your first sample should work. There is probably some other problem in your view so razor thinks your variable is not declared. Can you post your full view or upload it somewhere?

Comment: What is hidden behind  "//Stuff " comment? Something like @helper? Because it should work just fine as is...

Comment: It's mostly a bunch of html markup, with a few other code snippets, I'll post an edit with the stuff section filled in in a couple minutes as I format it into a more general case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try declaring the variable inside the first @{} block.  You would then be able to use the variable anywhere in the view.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I didn't realize the first one was considered a special case. I thought putting it near the code where it was used would be better stylistically.